# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mojo

Here is my clean install -x result:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\utopcu\workspace\test\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1254 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1254 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\utopcu\workspace\test\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ test ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1891)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:134)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:459)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.342s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 26 14:09:27 EEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project test: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.1.1/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.1/maven-archiver-2.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/1.0.1/plexus-io-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.13/plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>trest</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to delete repositories and install again. I got this error always. It looks like I need help. I think my mojo plugin is broken but i re installed it several times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? How did you call maven? I have checked the same pom with Maven 3.0.5, 3.1, 2.2.1 and it works without any problem. Have you cleaned your local repository and retried it?

Comment: Just clearing `~/.m2/repository/org/liquibase` solved it for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does the class `org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException` exist in `file:/C:/Users/utopcu/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar`?

The error message suggests that it doesn't. Maybe the JAR was corrupted somehow.

I'm also wondering where the version `1.0-beta-2` comes from; I have `1.0` on my disk. Try version `2.3` of the WAR plugin.

Comment: I had checked several times earlier if it was corrupted or non-existing. There was no problem. But when you answer my question it became magically corrupted:) Thanks for resolving btw.

Comment: i found a similar problem with a jar of thoughtworks which had got corrupted. Deleted the jar from m2 folder and did a mvn clean install again. It worked after that. Build was success

Answer (score 19):

Try to delete the maven folder at **~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven** and build your project again to force the maven libraries be downloaded. This worked for me the last time I faced this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilteringException.

Answer (score 9):

This should fix the error

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
             <version>1.3</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same issue and resolved by upgrading my Maven from 3.0.4 to 3.1.1. Please try with v3.1.1 or any higher version if available

Comment: Thank you. I faced the same issue and resolved by upgrading my Maven to 3.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading maven version from 3.0.4 to 3.2.3 worked for me.

Comment: After trying the other answers, this worked for me too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You should add **maven-resources-plugin** in your **pom.xml** file. Deleting **~/.m2/repository** does not work always.

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Now build your project again. It should be successful!

Answer (score 2):

this happened to me too after adding the version tag, that was missing, to the maven-war-plugin (not sure what version was using by default, i changed to the latest, 2.6 in my case). I had to wipe .m2/repository to have the build succeed again.

I tried first to clean the maven-filtering folder (in the repo) but then instead of a MavenFilterException i was getting an ArchiverException.
So i concluded the local repository was corrupted (for a version upgrade?) and i deleted everything.

That fixed it for me. Just clean your local repo.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Java version matches the project's Java version requirement. This could be an another cause for such kinds of issues.

Comment: This was my issue. The pom in the project didn't specify a maven version and I have many java versions installed on my machine with the latest being the default. So my maven was using JDK 13 but the project required 8. This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/43524685/4775820

Answer (score 1):

My solution below is for cases when default maven repositories are not accessible (e.g. due to firewalls).

In case the default repository is not accessible appropriate local `<pluginRepository>` has to be specified in the settings.xml. If it's the same as your local artifact repository it still needs to be added to the `<pluginRepositories>` section for plugin jars to be found. Regular `<repositories>` section is not used to fetch plugin jars.

In my case, however, the issue was caused by the fact that there were multiple plugin repositories defined in that section.

The first repository in the list did not contain the required maven-filtering jar.

I had to change the order of `<pluginRepository>` definitions to ensure the first one contains maven-filtering.

Changing of repository definitions typically requires to clean ~/.m2/repository and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the situation was this: I had an offline server on which I had to perform the build. For that I had compiled everything locally first and then transferred repository folder to the offline server.

Problem - build works locally but not on the server, even thou they both have same maven version, same repository folder, same JDK.

Cause: on my local machine I had additional custom "" entry in settings.xml. When I added same to the settings.xml on the server then my issues disappeared.

Comment: I think I have similar problem, but not sure what you mean with your settings.xml file?

Comment: It was quite some time ago, i do not remember the details and strangely i do not understand myself what i meant about the custom entry... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ten years on and I myself recently encountered this issue. The solution (for me) was to upgrade the version of maven-clean-plugin to 3.2.0