# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext

Tags: maven, noclassdeffounderror, oracle-coherence

I'm using maven-3.6.0 and using the Oracle's gar-maven-plugin in my pom file to package my project in to a GAR (which is Oracle coherence specific) and in process of doing so, the "mvn package" command is not allowing me to package the GAR and failing with the error below.

My Pom.xml file:

```
    <parent>
            <groupId>com.wellsfargo.coh</groupId>
            <artifactId>1COH_MainApp</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT-1.0</version>
    </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>session61-gar</artifactId> 
  <packaging>gar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.coherence</groupId>
      <artifactId>coherence</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.oracle.coherence</groupId>
        <artifactId>gar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-2-2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}\src\main\resources\lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

Error stack trace:

```
    [WARNING] Error injecting: com.oracle.maven.coherence.gar.GarPackageMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields (Class.java:1916)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields (InjectionPoint.java:760)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:670)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.BuildContext
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields (Class.java:1916)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields (InjectionPoint.java:760)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:670)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for 1COH_MainApp SNAPSHOT-1.0:
[INFO]
[INFO] 1COH_MainApp ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.063 s]
[INFO] session61-gar ...................................... FAILURE [ 14.915 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: Why have you added the plexus-build-api ?

Comment: I have added it because of this error in the stack trace - "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.BuildContext "

But even after adding the plexus-build-api the error still persist.

Answer (score 0):

I added maven-filtering dependency to maven-resources-plugin and it works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I found this decision here: [A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442753/a-required-class-was-missing-while-executing-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-war)